# Could AI create some kind of physical team-based sport?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, sports

If there was a very smart AI, could they create some kind of physical team-based sport and learn to play it. If the AI did create some kind of sport would they learn to work together and be a team?

Comment: If something was really smart, it would be smart enough to do [insert any mental task here]. It could very well communicate with [insert any kind of entity here] about [insert any topic/action here].

Comment: You talking about [ESports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESports) or about physical sport - both are possible, depends on which form AI have.

Comment: Define sports, and even then I would think this is opinion based.

Comment: If we're only talking about physical sports, then I think that we need to know more about the AI's mobile units.  What does the AI do?  Why does it have mobile units?  How does it get the mobile units?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the AI. I assume by AI you mean a robot of some sort. As robots have to keep their body functions in a good state it is possible that they would incorporate some kind of protocol, which causes them to "enjoy" physical exercise, as part of their daily maintenance.

As Robots would need social protocols too it is safe to assume that they would use those protocol not only with humans but with other robots too.

The connection of those two factors might lead to robots create some kind of team sport.

For any AI without a body it does not make much sense to create any kind of sport, as the sport by its nature is something done with the body.

Comment: It may require a definition of sport that is a bit more liberal, but I could imagine that AIs would have contests in things they can do without a body (trying to hack each other? Finding the largest unknown prime number?). Whether they enjoy it or not depends heavily on the specifics of their creation (and some parts of the nature of strong AI we simply don't know about).

Comment: They already play chess and go after all.